# Unable to create df with the specified schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

When I'm trying to create a dataframe with schema in the below code it isn't working and if did it without schema every column data is getting  clubbed into a single column

```
#transformations
val t3 = t1.map{case(a)=>(a(1).toInt,a(2))}.reduceByKey((x,y)=> `  
(x+","+y)).map{case(a,b)=>parse(a,b)}
```

Parse function returns Array[Int].

Code show here

```
`t3.collect()`  
res7: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2), Array(104,  
2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3))  
#schema column names
`temp`  
res11: List[String] = List(id, review, inprogress, notstarted, completed,   
started, total)  

`val fields = temp.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName,   
IntegerType, nullable = true))`  
fields: List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField]  
#creating schema
`val schema = StructType(fields)`  
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType  

`val df = t3.toDF()`  
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: array<int>]  

`df.show()`  
+--------------------+  
|               value|  
+--------------------+  
|[100, 1, 1, 0, 0,...|  
|[104, 2, 0, 0, 0,...|  
+--------------------+  

`val df = t3.toDF(schema)`  
error: type mismatch;  


`val df = spark.createDataFrame(t3)`  
<console>:35: error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with   
alternatives  

Expected:  
+---+---------+----------+----------+------+-------+-----+  
| id|completed|inprogress|notstarted|review|started|total|  
+---+---------+----------+----------+------+-------+-----+  
|100|        0|         1|         0|     1|      0|    2|  
|104|        0|         0|         0|     2|      1|    3|  
+---------+---+----------+----------+------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

from spark documentation you have:

```
def toDF(colNames: String*): DataFrame
```

But, you pass a `StructType` instance to `toDF` function.

You can create your second `Dataframe` with `t3.toDF(temp:_*)` (which convert to `toDF("id",.., "total")`

Furtermore, you should use `Array[(Int,..,Int)]` instead of `Array[Array[Int]]`

Comment: the thing is It should be able to dynamically know the no. of columns other than id and total. so I had only one option i.e array to return from function parse

Comment: How can I convert Array to tuple i.e Array[Array[Int]] => Array[(Int,..,Int)]. Is there any functionality to do that in scala

Comment: maybe somoething like `array.map { case Array(x,y,z) => (x,y,z) }` if your column number is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

RDD[Array[Int]] with parsed data can be converted to RDD[Row] and then converted to DataFrame:

```
val parsedData = Array(Array(100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2), Array(104,
  2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3))
val rddAfterParsing = sparkContext.parallelize(parsedData)
val rddOfRows = rddAfterParsing.map(arr => Row(arr: _*))

val columnNames = Seq("id", "review", "inprogress", "notstarted", "completed", "started", "total")
val fields = columnNames.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName,
  IntegerType, nullable = true))
val result = spark.createDataFrame(rddOfRows, StructType(fields))

result.show(false)
```

**Output:**

```
+---+------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----+
|id |review|inprogress|notstarted|completed|started|total|
+---+------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----+
|100|1     |1         |0         |0        |0      |2    |
|104|2     |0         |0         |0        |1      |3    |
+---+------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: I am getting those values dynamically. I didn't even mentioned about rdd creation statically.

Comment: Statically created RDD is just for example, have to be replaced with real.